# Carrying gradients from previous time steps to current time steps with GRU in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, gradient

I have the following model in tensorflow:

```
def output_layer(input_layer, num_labels):
    '''
    :param input_layer: 2D tensor
    :param num_labels: int. How many output labels in total? (10 for cifar10 and 100 for cifar100)
    :return: output layer Y = WX + B
    '''
    input_dim = input_layer.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
    fc_w = create_variables(name='fc_weights', shape=[input_dim, num_labels],
                            initializer=tf.uniform_unit_scaling_initializer(factor=1.0))
    fc_b = create_variables(name='fc_bias', shape=[num_labels], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    fc_h = tf.matmul(input_layer, fc_w) + fc_b
    return fc_h

def model(input_features):

    with tf.variable_scope("GRU"):
        cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(gru1_cell_size)

        cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(gru2_cell_size)

        mcell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell1, cell2], state_is_tuple=False)

        # shape=(?, 64 + 32) 
        initial_state = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, gru1_cell_size + gru2_cell_size], dtype=tf.float32, name="initial_state")
        output, new_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(mcell, input_features, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=initial_state)

    with tf.variable_scope("output_reshaped"):
        # before, shape: (34, 1768, 32), after, shape: (34 * 1768, 32)
        output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[-1, gru2_cell_size])

    with tf.variable_scope("output_layer"):
        # shape: (34 * 1768, 3)
        predictions = output_layer(output, num_labels)
        predictions = tf.reshape(predictions, shape=[-1, 100, 3])
    return predictions, initial_state, new_state, output
```

So as we can see from the code that the cell size of the first GRU is 64, the cell size of the second GRU is 32. And the batch size is 34 (but this is not important for me now). And the size of input features is 200. I have tried computing the gradients of the loss with respect to the trainable variables through:

```
local_grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
# only the gradients are taken to add them later with the back propagated gradients from previous batch.
local_grads = [grad for grad, var in local_grads_and_vars]

for v in local_grads:
    print("v", v)
```

After printing out the grads I got the following:

```
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/GRU_Layer1/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(264, 128), dtype=float32)
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/GRU_Layer1/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(128,), dtype=float32)
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/GRU_Layer1/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(264, 64), dtype=float32)
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/GRU_Layer1/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(64,), dtype=float32)
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/GRU_Layer2/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(96, 64), dtype=float32)
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/GRU_Layer2/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(64,), dtype=float32)
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/GRU_Layer2/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(96, 32), dtype=float32)
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/GRU_Layer2/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(32,), dtype=float32)
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/output_layer/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0", shape=(32, 3), dtype=float32)
v Tensor("Optimizer/gradients/output_layer/add_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0", shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

Assume that I saved the gradients after training the model on the first batch, that is, after feeding a tensor of shape: `(34, 100, 200)` as `input_features` "In the model function argument", and output of shape `(34 * 100, 3)`, how to back propagate these gradients on the second mini-batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution with a custom code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

cell_size = 32

seq_length = 1000

time_steps1 = 500
time_steps2 = seq_length - time_steps1

x_t = np.arange(1, seq_length + 1)    
x_t_plus_1 = np.arange(2, seq_length + 2)

tf.set_random_seed(123)

m_dtype = tf.float32

input_1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[None, time_steps1, 1], name="input_1")
input_2 = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[None, time_steps2, 1], name="input_2")

labels1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[None, time_steps1, 1], name="labels_1")
labels2 = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[None, time_steps2, 1], name="labels_2")

labels = tf.concat([labels1, labels2], axis=1, name="labels")

def model(input_feat1, input_feat2):
    with tf.variable_scope("GRU"):
        cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(cell_size)
        cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(cell_size)

        initial_state = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, cell_size], dtype=m_dtype, name="initial_state")

        with tf.variable_scope("First50"):
            # output1: shape=[1, time_steps1, 32]
            output1, new_state1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell1, input_feat1, dtype=m_dtype, initial_state=initial_state)

        with tf.variable_scope("Second50"):
            # output2: shape=[1, time_steps2, 32]
            output2, new_state2 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell2, input_feat2, dtype=m_dtype, initial_state=new_state1)

        with tf.variable_scope("output"):
            # output shape: [1, time_steps1 + time_steps2, 32] => [1, 100, 32]
            output = tf.concat([output1, output2], axis=1)

            output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[-1, cell_size])
            output = tf.layers.dense(output, units=1)
            output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[1, time_steps1 + time_steps2, 1])

        with tf.variable_scope("outputs_1_2_reshaped"):
            output1 = tf.slice(input_=output, begin=[0, 0, 0], size=[-1, time_steps1, -1])
            output2 = tf.slice(input_=output, begin=[0, time_steps1, 0], size=[-1, time_steps2, 1])

            print(output.get_shape().as_list(), "1")
            print(output1.get_shape().as_list(), "2")
            print(output2.get_shape().as_list(), "3")

            return output, output1, output2, initial_state, new_state1, new_state2

def loss(output, output1, output2, labels, labels1, labels2):
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.sqrt(tf.square(output - labels)))
    loss1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.sqrt(tf.square(output1 - labels1)))
    loss2 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.sqrt(tf.square(output2 - labels2)))
    return loss, loss1, loss2

def optimize(loss, loss1, loss2, initial_state, new_state1, new_state2):
     with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
        update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

        with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)

            grads1 = tf.gradients(loss2, new_state1)
            grads2 = tf.gradients(loss1, initial_state)
            grads3 = tf.gradients(new_state1, initial_state, grad_ys=grads1)

            grads_wrt_initial_state_1 = tf.add(grads2, grads3)
            grads_wrt_initial_state_2 = tf.gradients(loss, initial_state, grad_ys=None)

            return grads_wrt_initial_state_1, grads_wrt_initial_state_2

output, output1, output2, initial_state, new_state1, new_state2 = model(input_1, input_2)

loss, loss1, loss2 = loss(output, output1, output2, labels, labels1, labels2)

grads_wrt_initial_state_1, grads_wrt_initial_state_2 = optimize(loss, loss1, loss2, initial_state, new_state1, new_state2)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    in1 = np.reshape(x_t[:time_steps1], newshape=(1, time_steps1, 1))
    in2 = np.reshape(x_t[time_steps1:], newshape=(1, time_steps2, 1))
    l1 = np.reshape(x_t_plus_1[:time_steps1], newshape=(1, time_steps1, 1))
    l2 = np.reshape(x_t_plus_1[time_steps1:], newshape=(1, time_steps2, 1))
    i_s = np.zeros([1, cell_size])

    t1, t2 = sess.run([grads_wrt_initial_state_1, grads_wrt_initial_state_2], feed_dict={input_1: in1,
                                                                                         input_2: in2,
                                                                                         labels1: l1,
                                                                                         labels2: l2,
                                                                                         initial_state: i_s})
    print(np.mean(t1), np.mean(t2))
    print(np.sum(t1), np.sum(t2))
```

This is an example of 2 GRUs one after the other, and I did back propagation in 2 different ways according to the code in `optimize()`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `tf.gradients`

> `grad_ys` is a list of tensors of the same length as `ys` that holds the initial gradients for each y in `ys`. When `grad_ys` is None, we fill in a tensor of '1's of the shape of y for each y in `ys`. A user can provide their own initial `grad_ys` to compute the derivatives using a different initial gradient for each y (e.g., if one wanted to weight the gradient differently for each value in each y).

So your `grad_ys` should be a list with the same length as the input `ys`.

Copying your code I was able to get the following to run:

```
prev_grad_pl = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch, i]) for i in [64, 32]]
prev_grad_init = {l: np.ones(l.get_shape().as_list()) for l in prev_grad_pl}
prev_grads_val__ = tf.gradients([new_state1, new_state2], [initial_state1, initial_state2], grad_ys=prev_grad_pl)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    feed = {initial_state1: np.zeros([batch, gru1_cell_size]),
            initial_state2: np.zeros([batch, gru2_cell_size])}

    for k in prev_grad_init:
        feed[k] = prev_grad_init[k]

    grad1, grad2 = sess.run(prev_grads_val__, feed_dict=feed)
```

Comment: This will create a working code, but in reality you won't be able to find the gradients of `new_state2` with respect to `initial_state1`. So I solved this problem by creating 2 cells as shown in the original code, and then I added them to a `MultiRNNCell` with `state_is_tuple=False`. Then the `MulriRNNCell` is added to the `dynamic_rnn`. As a result, I will be left off with `new_state` and `initial_state` only. Yet I need to know who to propagate the gradients back ward.

Comment: I have edited the question above. So please take into account the modifications mentioned. @McAngus, your help is much appreciated!!